# pytorch F.cross_entropy does not apply gradient to weights

Tags: pytorch, gradient

I'm trying to train an MLP from scratch using `torch` tensors and some of the built-in loss functions. I have IRIS-data downloaded and stored in tensor `(100, 4)` and labels `(100)` (integers 0-2) in `data_tr` and `targets_tr`.  I have enabled gradients on the input data `data_tr.requires_grad=True`

I have a 2-layer MLP initialized like this:

```
W1 = torch.randn([4, 64], requires_grad=True)
W2 = torch.randn([64, 3], requires_grad=True)
b1 = torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)
b2 = torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True
```

I understand that I should train like this:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    W1.grad = None
    W2.grad = None
    b1.grad = None
    b2.grad = None

    f = torch.relu(data_tr @ W1 + b1) @ W2 + b2
    error = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(f, targets_tr)
    error.backward()

    W1 = W1 - lr * W1.grad
    W2 = W2 - lr * W2.grad
    b1 = b1 - lr * b1.grad
    b2 = b2 - lr * b2.grad
```

Which makes a 2 layer MLP and cross_entropy applies softmax. 
The problem now is that none of the weights or biases (W1, W2, b1, b2) has any gradients after the backward pass. So I get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'` on the first attempt to updating a weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the weights without using an optimizer, you have to either use `torch.no_grad()` or update their `data` directly to ensure autograd is not tracking the update operations.

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    W1 -= lr * W1.grad
    W2 -= lr * W2.grad

b1.data = b1 - lr * b1.grad
b2.data = b2 - lr * b2.grad
```

Note in the first case, if you do not subtract assign, the `requires_grad` will be set to `False` for the weights which again will result in `None` values for the gradients.

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    W1 = W1 - lr * W1.grad
    W2 = W2 - lr * W2.grad
print(W1.requires_grad, W2.requires_grad)
>>> False False
```

Comment: Updating the data-field directly solved the issue. Thanks.